# Can R process a pdf with text in it?

Tags: r

For example, can I input a PDF file into R and have it scan the text and transform it into a format that can be manipulated (e.g. somehow detect certain words in the text, or perform machine learning by inputting lots of pdf and detecting words in them)?

Additionally, can R differentiate **bolded** or *italicized* text, large size headings, indent, and other standard formatting, and assign certain values to such bolded text? 
If not, what is an alternative method to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking if there are R packages that can parse PDF files? What did your search of CRAN reveal? A simple google search of "R packages pdf" turns up some promising hits.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out the [`pdftools` package](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools). You can also check out [this article](https://blog.datazar.com/extracting-pdf-text-with-r-and-creating-tidy-data-f399011549cc) about how to use `pdftools` in combination with the `stringr` package to clean a pdf.